# foregin key using name value fetch in django rest frame work

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

i have add model.py ,view.py and serilializer.py file ,i will share country and state model .
I wiil apply foregin key country and state fields.
I will check in html fields in django rest framework in only object id fetch not value so like city(Morbi).

[image: htmlview]

[image: views.py]

[[image: model.pyserlializer.py]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Override the  `__str__()` function in model class to customize the dropdown correctly.

```
class Country(models.Model):
    # your data variables
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name # or any thing you want to show in dropdown
```

same you can do with state too.

Answer (score 0):

As Vinay has stated, add a return method to return some sort of detail to all your models. Also, make sure your model names start with a capital letter and there is no need to define the id as Django will always create that for you.